# Does encrypting a key (stored in cookie) increase security?

Tags: encryption, php, xss, cookies, session-management

**Scenario**

- Master key is entered upon login then encrypted with `$server_key`
- Master key is now stored as `$_COOKIE['encrypted_key']` variable for persistence (so user doesn't have to enter it every page load)
- `$server_key` is stored inside a config file in the app server
- Data is decrypted by first decrypting `$_COOKIE['encrypted_key']` (using `$server_key`), therefore revealing Master key
- `$_COOKIE['encrypted_key']` is destroyed upon browser exit

**Threat**

Attacker gaining access to user device/cookie and encrypted data (but not the app server config files).

**Question**

Does it make sense to encrypt the Master key with `$server_key` and then store `$server_key` inside a config file in the app server?

**Reasoning**

Gaining just the `$server_key` or just the `$_COOKIE['encrypted_key']` will not compromise anything. The attacker must get both.

**Update**

- This is under HTTPS
- Session hijacking would be hard as we check session fingerprint per request

Comment: This is pretty similar to your [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440565/how-to-protect-encryption-key-from-server-admin/39440834#comment66204217_39440834)

Comment: Also, how are you going to encrypt the key in `$_COOKIE['encrypted_key']` in the *first request* from client to server if the master key is on the app server?

Comment: @grochmal The app simply requests for it e.g., `get_key_from_config()`

Comment: That's what I thought, but how do you prevent an attacker from simply requesting it.  i.e. *Hey server, i'm app 1234.  Give me the key to encrypt my stuff*.  And then the attacker simply decrypts the cookie.

Comment: @grochmal This is a web app. To do the thing you describe means the attacker gained root access already.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant, sorry.  I mean, for example, sniffing the request and replaying it from his own machine.

Comment: @grochmal The attacker can do that only if he gained both the cookie and the user credentials. e.g., He is pretty much acting as the actual user.

Comment: Hmm... after thinking  I still find it very confusing: You argue that the threat model is an attacker getting that cookie, yet you have a manner for which the attacker cannot get user credentials.  Both these things sound like opposites.  If you are exchanging data over, say, HTTPS the attacker will not be able to get either credentials or the cookie.  If over plain HTTP he would be able to get both.  (I'm not considering stuff like sslstrip here)

Comment: @grochmal Credential persistence (being logged in) are not stored in `$_COOKIE` but in `$_SESSION`. If the attacker manages to get `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE`, he's in. So yeah if the attacker gets a hold of the device while the user is logged in, he is in. But replaying that scenario in another device will be difficult.

Comment: Or sniff the traffic and replay quickly enough (a very likely scenario). `$_SESSION` is inherently insecure.  You would just sniff a header like `Cookie: SessionID=3` and you have the session.  The attacker can send the same session ID and he has both `$_SESSION` (in the PHP context) and `$_COOKIE` he has already.  There is (almost) no extra security provided by using `$_SESSION`. (the only thing that `$_SESSION` provides in extra security is session expiry).

Comment: @grochmal But this is in HTTPS so doing that would be hard. And even if the attacker gets the session id, our session handler also checks basic session fingerprint to prevent session hi-jacking.

Comment: OK, there is HTTPS, so yeah: the simple answer to "does it make sense to encrypt that cookie" is **no**.  If the attacker can get through HTTPS, he can get everything.  If he cannot get through HTTPS he gets nothing. That extra key passing around would only be unneeded overhead.  PS: It may be useful to update the question with the summary of these comments and the comments under wireghoul's answer (I did not understood the HTTPS in there sorry :) ), so we can get rid of this scroll of death of comments.

Comment: @grochmal What if I want to hide the key from the user? I mean, without encryption, the key is stored in plaintext in the cookie. Is there any possible threat seeing the key in plaintext in the cookie?

Comment: If I remember correctly (from the SO question) the reason for the key is to protect data from the server admin.  In that case the user knows the key.  There is not point in protecting a key from someone who knows it.  Even if that is not the case here, the user could simply use tamper data and get all HTTPS in plain text.  In general: there is absolutely no secure way (in symmetric cryptography) to send a key and the encrypted data over the same media.

Comment: @grochmal The threat model here is different. SO is for threat against admin but here it's threat against an attacker. Well I always have the assumption that extra layer is better, I still don't feel comfortable putting the key "naked" in the browser cookie. Anyway there is still an unanswered question: how can the attacker replay this if his attack doesn't pass our session finger print check?

Answer (score 6):

Your threat model is incomplete. Here are some of the things you missed:

1) The master key and server key appear to be static values. This means the cookie value is constant and anyone that has the cookie value can replay it to the server to steal (spider) all the plaintext data for that user.

1a) Cookies gets stored in other locations too such as proxies.

2) If the server is compromised an attacker can brute force the master key space to decrypt the user data on a per user basis. The success chance of this depends entirely on the master key length and encryption algorithm.

3) A user can derive the server key. As they know the master key and can view the cookie they can brute force the server key offline. Again success factor is dependant upon key length and algorithm.

4) It's unclear if the service is being delivered over an encrypted of plain text connection. In the case of the latter both the master key and cookie value can be observed by an attacker on the same network. If the former the connection may be downgraded or other vulnerabilities may exist.

5) **If the attacker hacks the server they can modify the login code to keep a copy of all master keys it receives.** It is common for breaches to go unnoticed for months/years.

Comment: 1. Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't keys static in nature? Otherwise you have to re-encrypt everything all the time. The purpose of the `$server_key` is to defeat cookie replays, they can replay but they don't know the `$server_key`.

Comment: 2. I agree although bruteforce requires knowing the algo used and serious will/compute power

Comment: 3. Sorry I don't get this because the user cannot derive the `$server_key` at all. The app handles encrypt/decrypt in the server side. The only thing the user has in his browser is `$_COOKIE['encrypted_key']`

Comment: 4. It is using HTTPS

Comment: 5. I agree. To complete data breach, the attacker must do 3 things: obtain `$server_key`,  obtain `$_COOKIE['encrypted_key']`, obtain database access.

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose of the $server_key is to defeat cookie replays, they can replay but they don't know the $server_key

Encrypting the master key with server key doesn't defeat replay attack. The attacker can just send the send the encrypted master key to your server and have it decrypt whatever data the attacker wanted. Your server becomes a [confused deputy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem). The attacker doesn't need to compromise the server or obtain the server key to do this.

To limit this attack, you can add an expiry date and IP address inside the encrypted master key, i.e. Encrypt(MasterKey + Expiry + IP address), your server should only use the encrypted token if it is not expired and the request comes from the given IP address.

Comment: Can you explain how can the attacker replay the session on his machine given that we have HTTPS + session fingerprint checks?

Comment: @IMB: if you assume the threat model is that both ends of the communication are secure, HTTPS already protects against replay attack. Additional encryption of the master key that's already inside HTTPS does not confer any extra protection. Given that the extra extortion doesn't really add any extra protection, the encryption is just extra, unnecessary complexity. If your threat model involves the client side being possibly compromised, then just encrypting the master key is insufficient to protect against replay attack.

Comment: @IMB: my point is that you should either just simplify the code and remove the unnecessary master key encryption; or if you want to take client compromise into account, you should go all the way and encrypt the master key and the session fingerprint (e.g. IP, expiry date, capabilities) **together** to mitigate replay attack.

Comment: @IMB - session fingerprint is poor security (unless you're using something like full passive fingerprinting).  I need to argue that your thread model is horrible: you keep adding more "tinfoil" as people point the holes in the threat model and then we poke more and more holes in the tinfoil.  You need to put all pieces together (and I mean all of them) into the question text and think it through.  I do not mean it as a bad thing: just the exercise of putting all those pieces together will make the picture clearer for yourself.

Comment: @grochmal What tinfoil am I adding? Am I not adding things as we go, they are really there beforehand, I just didn't explicitly say them because I assume they are common sense for things like this e.g., SSL.

Comment: @IMB - let session fingerprinting be my tinfoil example :). But yeah, we need you to give us a decent summary of all info you can.  Asking a good question is hard and requires a good deal of thinking.  Managing the question is not an easy task either.  In other words, most of us here are having fun whilst we try to make the world a safer place, but we just cannot go into your head and take the info by ourselves.  And yeah, questions that break common sense happen (not that this is necessary one).  We want to help you, but you're making it hard to do it :(

Comment: @LieRyan My reasoning for encrypting the master key is because my threat model is literally like this: Good guy user leaves browser window open and goes to the bathroom. Bad guy quickly sits down on good guy's desk, views cookies and takes a photo of the encrypted master key (and possibly session id). How can we prevent the bad guy from replaying this?